# Python code to get stock prices

Tags: python-2.7

I've been trying to figure out this code snippet since two days,but in vain and cannot make anything out of it .Can you please explain the functioning of this code(What does the code do and how does it do it)?Also,how do I run it in the python shell ?I have just begun coding in python.The indentation is useless but stack overflow forced me to in the code

Code:

```
import nsetools
import random as r    
nse=nsetools.Nse()
print(nse)
nifty_quote = nse.get_index_quote('nifty 50')
print'Percentage change in nifty is:',nifty_quote['pChange'],'%'
pc=nifty_quote['pChange']
```

Edit: added proper code formatting.

Comment: This code looks very similar to the examples in the documentation, did you read over this example http://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#and-the-index-quote ? If anything still doesn't make sense let us know.

Comment: Thank you .That link solved the functioning part of the code .How do I run that code ?Whenever I try to run ,it throws me an error saying there is no nsetools module and no six module .I have downloaded the nsetools module in my machine and stored both of them in the same folder.What can the issue be and how do I resolve it? I do have the .WHL format of the six module installed .

Comment: Thanks joohn for the proper code format and thank you downshift ,that link is pretty useful .Got the code up and running